# Find the match percentage between two strings in php?

Tags: php, string, string-comparison, fuzzy-logic

can anyone suggest me a better method(or most preferred method) to find the match percentage between two strings(i.e. how closely those two strings(eg. name) are related in terms of percentage) using fuzzy logic.? can anyone help me to write the code? really i am wondering where to start..

Comment: Using some fuzzy logic? Sure, here's one: `$matchPercentage = ($str1 == $str2) ? 100 : 0;`. Seriously though, can you elaborate?

Comment: By "better", I assume you have already seen PHP's own [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/similar_text) and [levenshtein()](http://www.php.net/levenshtein)?

Comment: i am not sure.. i just need a better method to find the percentage match(i mean almost all comparisons) between two name strings..though i googled it, i cannot conclude which to choose? sry..if i am not clear.. @netcoder

Comment: `$matchPercentage = (levenstein($str1, $str2) / strlen($str1)) * 100`?

Comment: or `levenstein()` or `soundex()`

Comment: ya i ve seen levenshtein() and similar_text()..but unable to conclude which one is better?? i mean which one is more closest. or i am also looking for someone to suggest any manual algorithm which calculates the percentage match. @user113215

Comment: for example say if i am comparing "muzaf" and "naren". the result i am getting from levenshtein() is 100% match.. which is not true. so am looking for someone to suggest any manual logic.. @DaveRandom

Comment: None is better, it depends what you want to do. What are you looking for exactly? Difference in characters? spelling? stemming? length? pronounciation? synonyms?

Comment: @user1518659 But those two strings *are* 100% different, they have none of the same characters in the same positions. What result do you want from those two strings and, more importantly, why - what logic do you want to use?

Answer (score 12):

```
$str1 = 'Hello';
$str2 = 'Hello, World!';
$percent;
similar_text($str1, $str2, $percentage);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: There is no need to $percent

Answer (score 10):

### Word Comparator

Here's a comparison based on words - it's *a lot faster* than character-based ones, plus it often makes more sense to compare human text by words. However, word lengths do matter; this algorithm takes this into consideration, for better results. Check test results at the end; I think they're pretty much what a human would say.

```
function wordSimilarity($s1,$s2) {

    $words1 = preg_split('/\s+/',$s1);
    $words2 = preg_split('/\s+/',$s2);
    $diffs1 = array_diff($words2,$words1);
    $diffs2 = array_diff($words1,$words2);

    $diffsLength = strlen(join("",$diffs1).join("",$diffs2));
    $wordsLength = strlen(join("",$words1).join("",$words2));
    if(!$wordsLength) return 0;

    $differenceRate = ( $diffsLength / $wordsLength );
    $similarityRate = 1 - $differenceRate;
    return $similarityRate;

}
```

This function gives you a floating point value between 0 and 1 where 1 is total similarity.

##### Let's see some tests

```php
    $test = "this is something you've never done before";
    
    wordSimilarity($test,"this is something you've never done before");  //  1.000
    wordSimilarity($test,"this is something");                           //  0.588
    wordSimilarity($test,"this is nothing you have ever done");          //  0.312
    wordSimilarity($test,"leave me alone with lorem ipsum");             //  0.000
    wordSimilarity($test,"before you do something you've never done");   //  0.845
    wordSimilarity($test,"never have i ever done this");                 //  0.448
```