# How to search phrase with soundex using 1 word?

Tags: php, mysql, fuzzy-search

I need to find this phrase 'small side table' with this word 'table' or 'tablr' or 'tables' if the user makes a mistake typing only 1 word in the input.

I tried MATCH AGAINST and LIKE '%%', but simulating the error writing, it doesn't find anything, to correct it i need the whole sentence soundex('small side tablr'), but i only have 'tables' to search

```
$search="tables";

$data = $connection->query("SELECT title from `posts` where soundex(`title`) = soundex('$search') ");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the match percentage between two strings in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161828/find-the-match-percentage-between-two-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should try to use MySQL's regular expression functions to search the text.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr

In your specific case (find the phrase 'small side table'), suppose that user input search keywords: 'table' or 'tablr' or 'tables' or 'rable', then in PHP code, we need to change search keyword to be a proper pattern, for example:

```
$search = "table";  // or 'tablr' or 'tables' or 'rable'

// define pattern which allow misspellings last letters
$regex_pattern = substr($search, 0, 4).".{1,2}"; # now pattern is 'tabl.{1,2}'

// then add an alternative pattern, which allow misspellings first letter
$regex_pattern .= "|.".substr($search, 1);  # now pattern is 'tabl.{1,2}|.able'

// then we could add other patterns as needs..

$data = $connection->query("SELECT title FROM `posts` WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(`title`, '$regex_pattern') ");
```

You have to modify search parameters to suit your needs (and learn a little bit about regular expression too if you haven't used it before https://regexone.com/).

You could try out MySQL's regular expression functions by using sql playground online here
https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yukq8apv

It is noteworthy that regular expression could be slow, especially with complex search pattern. So we have to consider how many misspellings patterns which are supported.

Comment: Trung Duong Thanks for your cooperation, but i told you that the user will not have access to the phrase 'small side table', he will only type 'table' or table with misspellings, inside the search field. And if i have thousands of phrases in the database as 'small coffee table' or 'wood chairs', do i have to use 4 regular expressions for each word in the sentence?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my suggestion. My suggested queries are only the samples of how string matches regular expression with REGEXP_LIKE function. I've edit the answer to make my suggestion clearer, please check.